# Maximum and mean value is different in Python than QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, landsat-8, rasterio

I read a Landsat-8 TIFF file using Python Rasterio to compute the max and mean using the following code:

```
path = "LC08_L1TP_115036_20181025_20181031_01_T1_B7.TIF"
test = rasterio.open(path).read()
print("value of max and mean", test.max(), test.mean())
```

`value of max and mean 65535 4390.264887378426`

But when I opened the same image in QGIS 3.6 it gives the different values as mentioned below:

```
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=41986
STATISTICS_MEAN=4629.7234448245
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=3599.2731482793
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
```

Can anyone tell me the reason for the same which one I should consider correct?

Moreover, since 65535 is the highest possible value in 16-bit integer, what does the pixels having value of 65535 in Band 1 to 10 of Landsat-8 denote?

Comment: 65535 is the highest possible value from a 16 bit integer. My guess is that that value is filtered away in QGIS as it would indicate some kind of error or unusable data and then the highest value left is 41986. python rasterio just reads all the data. What would be interesting is to see  how much of the image / which parts of the image has that value. (I got curious and googled around a bit to see if it anywhere was indicated what to do whith 65535 values in landsat images, but did not find anything, which talks against my understanding...)

Comment: Ya, that's correct 65535 is the highest possible value from a 16-bit integer. But my question is what's the possibility of a pixel having value to be 65535. What does it denotes in let's say band 7. Also, which one i should consider the correct Python or QGIS?

Comment: My theory is that the 65535 valus should be considered invalid, so that QGIS is correct, but that is just a theory ... Look at the general distribution of data, do those cells fit in with the rest? How are they compared to the neigbors?

Comment: I filtered the 65535 from numpy array before calculating the max. But again i am getting the maximum around 64000 and again i filtered value above 60000 and then i got the max to be around 59000. So, it's not just giving the max value to be wrong the underlying values are different. So, what could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QGIS, You need to change the statistic extent to actual instead of estimate (which uses overviews) as mentioned [here](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/1824). Also shown here in the image below :

[image]